# Why is this 2d array pushing values when it shouldn't?

Tags: javascript, arrays

EDITED: Thanks for pointing out my oblivious mistake with tempRndNumber being reset in the inner loop. 
I'm still seeing "," characters show up in the array though.

I want to create a 2d array that only gets populated when a random number meets a particular criteria (rnd >= 7). But the following code populates the 2d array with a combination of "," and the numbers that meets the criteria.

```
var tempAllRndNumbers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            var tempRndNumber = [];
            var rndNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            if (rndNumber >= 7) {
                tempRndNumber.push(rndNumber);
            }
        }
        tempAllRndNumbers.push(tempRndNumber);
    }
```

tempAllRndNumbers should only be populated with numbers 7 and above, right? But instead, I'm getting a 2D array full of "," and numbers 7 and above.

Comment: *"I want to create a 2d array"* (...) *"should only be populated with numbers 7 and above, right? But instead, I'm getting a 2D array"*.. the post seems a little contraditory...

Comment: You reset the `tempRndNumber` array every time in the inner loop.

Comment: @Juhana That's intentional, note there are two array variables.

Comment: @Nit I don't think so. Then the inner loop wouldn't make any sense because only the last iteration has any effect.

Comment: What do you mean you're seeing "," characters? How are you outputting the array?

Comment: I updated my answer with a fiddle to show that there are no commas in the output

Comment: @jessikwa:  console.log(tempAllRndNumbers)

Comment: that's your problem. Look at the fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to reset `tempRndNumber` in each iteration of your inner loop like you are. Try this:

```
                    var tempAllRndNumbers = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        var tempRndNumber = [];
                        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                            var rndNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
                            if (rndNumber >= 7) {
                                tempRndNumber.push(rndNumber);
                            }
                        }
                        tempAllRndNumbers.push(tempRndNumber);
                    }
```

UPDATE: 
You have to loop back through both arrays to get the proper output, see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/1fbq0woo/

Comment: No problem, friend. Don't forget to select an answer if your issue is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you reset `tempRndNumber` to an empty array on each iteration of the `j` loop, it will only contain a number if the last iteration was >= 7.  Move the initialization outside of the innermost loop:

```
var tempAllRndNumbers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var tempRndNumber = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; {
            var rndNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            if (rndNumber >= 7) {
                tempRndNumber.push(rndNumber);
            }
        }
        tempAllRndNumbers.push(tempRndNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no check to see if the tempRndNumber array has any values, so you are pushing an empty array into the array tempAllRndNumbers. That's why you have the ','s, you have indexes with no values.

Comment: But doesn't the if (rndNumber >=7) prove that there is a value to be pushed?

Comment: No, it only proves that if there is a value that is 7 or greater it will be pushed, if the loop generates no values of 7+, tempRndNumber will be empty when you push it to tempAllRndNumbers, so if it was on the first loop for example, tempAllRndNumbers[0] === [ ]

Comment: While this wasn't the main issue it is a good point. When pushing to `tempAllRndNumbers` I'd first do a check that says `if (tempRndNumber && tempRndNumber.length) { tempAllRndNumbers.push(tempRndNumber); }`